# How to open RTMP stream in VLC?

Tags: vlc, rtmp

I cannot figure out how to play RTMP stream from VLC. I can view it on the web through flash player without problems. I found the information about the stream through firebug:

```xml
<data>
  <smilRoot>
    <body>
      <switchItem id="0-BO-18166" base="rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz/ct-vod/_definst_?id=HRr8GUgv1FcCBzw1-01&amp;publisher=lss" begin="0" duration="134" clipBegin="0" type="recorded" stat="ProjectId=3;ApplicationId=4;NodeId=9">
        <video src="mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_720p.mp4" system-bitrate="3500" label="720p" enabled="true" />
        <video src="mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_576p.mp4" system-bitrate="2000" label="576p" enabled="true" />
        <video src="mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4" system-bitrate="1000" label="404p" enabled="true" />
        <video src="mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_288p.mp4" system-bitrate="500" label="288p" enabled="true" />
      </switchItem>
    </body>
  </smilRoot>
</data>
```

I was trying to play the 404p stream using rtmpdump, vlc, and also their combination. I am not quite sure how to glue the URL, however I tried all the combinations I could think of. Some examples I tried:

```
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss?mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/?mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss?iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/?iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4
```

Here is what rtpdump says:

```
$ rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4"
RTMPDump v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
WARNING: You haven't specified an output file (-o filename), using stdout
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

VLC just keeps throwing errors:

```
[00007f7918008088] avio access error: Failed to open rtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defins.t_?id=HRraUUgv1FKF42a-02&publisher=lss/mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4: Unknown error 833925547
```

By the way I sniffed the RTMP packets with wireshark, and the communication looks like this:

```
>..K..O...@...p.....>pb....#../.R.yj...VE`..i.?...Z.....0....'{~.....#.Q.4!.L.Ee."j.....<.(.........+....0K...~.......x. ...r.-.%O...4[d.........D.|L.
........,..bv.D..............K..MDg./w..:...t.../.R?...^d6...g...].4.....p.?fd9.2.C..._...V../...1z,....EB..ffS`=g...+....I1;...*P...)....S...iS...............connect.?..........app..4ct-vod/_definst_?id=HRs8fcCPpFaC6ea-02&publisher=lss..flashVer...LNX 11,2,202,406..swfUrl..Thttp://i.mgct.ceskatelevize.cz/global/swf/player/player_1.45.19c.swf?version=1.45.19c..tcUrl..Rrtmp://wcdn101.nacevi.cz:1935/ct-vod/_defi.nst_?id=HRs8fcCPpFaC6ea-02&publisher=lss..fpad....capabilities.@m........audioCodecs.@.........videoCodecs.@o.......
videoFuncti.on.?.........pageUrl...http://www.ceskatelevize.cz..objectEncoding.@.......................&%..............&%..................................................._result.?..........fmsVer...FMS/3,5,7,7009..capabilities.@?........mode.?.............level...status..code...NetConnection.Connect.Success..description...Connection succeeded...data.......version..
3,5,7,7009.....clientid.A..L8.....objectEncoding.@.............m.........&%....t............createStream.@........................_result.@.........?.......B.....
...........C.....[.....FCSubscribe............?mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4...............
onFCSubscribe...........
...level.
status.code.)NetStream.Play.Start.description..%FCSubscribe to stream iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4..clientid.A..L8.......{..f.........play............?mp4:iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4..........A.[...............................onStatus.............level...status..code...NetStream.Play.Reset..description..RPlaying and resetting iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4...clientid.A..L8..........................................E..........onStatus.............level...status..code...NetStream.Play.Start..description..LStarted playing iVysilani/2014/10/08/KristynaLiskaBokCT-081014-MP4_404p.mp4...clientid.A..L8....
```

I am sure I'm doing something wrong, can anyone give me a hint how to play this stream?

Comment: Did you have any success?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to play RTMP stream with VLC too without success and was getting the same error like you.

`Unknown error 833925547`

and also with `rtmpdump` I was also getting `ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound`

I was using VLC 2.1.6 which comes with Ubuntu 14.04 and the the respective version of rtmpdump.

So, it happened that I gave the rtmp url to a friend with Windows OS, and one with Mac OS. They both opened my URL without problems.

It is possible that VLC uses some backend on Linux that is broken (i.e. rtmpdump).

I guess I have to file a bug for VLC, I did upgrade the 2.1.6 VLC in Ubuntu 14.04 to 2.2.1 - it didn't work again. I tried in a Windows by myself (2.2.1) and it OPENED!

So far my current status is as follows:

```
    Ubuntu 14.04 
    VLC 2.1.6 - CANNOT OPEN the rtmp that I provide (myself)
    VLC 2.2.1 - CANNOT OPEN the rtmp that I provide (myself)

    Windows
    VLC 2.1.5 - OPENS WITHOUT PROBLEM the rtmp I provide (my friend)
    VLC 2.2.1 - OPENS WITHOUT PROBLEM the rtmp I provide (myself)

    Mac OS
    VLC 2.2.1 - OPENS WITHOUT PROBLEM the rtmp I provide (my friend)
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug, should be reported to the VLC team. https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_bugs/#Still_a_bug.3F